# Size (width/height) constraints on diff elements in UIStackView overriding each others' constraints

Tags: swift

I am currently placing a UIImageView with a fixed width and height constraint of 20 and a UIView underneath that UIImageView. But the UIView has a width of 20, same as the UIImageView but when I add a width constraint of 10 to the UIView the UIImageView becomes 10x10... Below is my implementation: -

```
        guard let superview = superview else { return }
        verticalStack = UIStackView()

        verticalStack?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        verticalStack?.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        verticalStack?.axis = .vertical
        verticalStack?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        verticalStack?.spacing = 5.0

        brightnessIcon = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "brightness.png"))
        brightnessIcon?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        brightnessIcon?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
        brightnessIcon?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
        verticalStack?.addArrangedSubview(brightnessIcon!)

        brightnessIndicator = UIView()
        brightnessIndicator?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        brightnessIndicator?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5.0).isActive = true
        verticalStack?.addArrangedSubview(brightnessIndicator!)
```

Below is the image before I add the width constraint to the brightnessIndicator (UIView):-

[image]

After adding width constraint to the brightnessIndicator:-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your stackView's `alignment`. By default this is set to `fill` which tries to layout the arranged subviews to fill the opposite axis of your stackView (in your case they will be filled `horizontally`).

Try setting the alignment to `leading`, `trailing`, or `centered` (you have to check for yourself what fits your needs). As these alignment options don't force the arranged subviews to resize.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set distribution and alignment of your stackView

```
        verticalStack?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        verticalStack?.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        verticalStack?.axis = .vertical
        verticalStack?.alignment = .center
        verticalStack?.distribution = .fillProportionally
```